# getting error Cannot read property 'validator' of undefined in [null],also Error during evaluation of "click"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am using below code but getting errors..i am unable to find where i am wrong:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'validator' of undefined in
>       [null]

Also when i click on Create button getting below error

[image]

**Testing.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig}                 from 'angular2/router';

//---------Import External Components---------

    import {TestingMain}                                    from './Testing.main';

    @Component({
        selector: 'testing',
        templateUrl: `app/Testing/Testing.view.html`
    })
    @RouteConfig([
            { path: '/', name: 'ManageTesting', component: TestingMain, useAsDefault: true },
    ])
    export class Testing {
        constructor() {
        }
    }
```

**Testing.main.ts**

```
 //---------Import Angular2------------
    import {Component, OnInit}                                     from 'angular2/core';
    import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http}                                  from 'angular2/http';
    import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig}                        from 'angular2/router';
    import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,
        FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup, Validators}            from 'angular2/common';

    //---------Import External Components---------
    import {Testingmodel}               from './Testing.model';
    import {TestingService}             from './Testing.service';
    //---------Declare Components---------
    @Component({
        selector: 'Testing-list',
        templateUrl: `app/Testing/Testing.view.html`,
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
        providers: [TestingService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
    })

    //---------Export This Component Class---------
    export class TestingMain implements OnInit {

        public resmessage: string;
        public addmessage: string;
        public listmessage: string;
        public contact: Testingmodel;
        public editContactId: any

        testingForm: ControlGroup;
        firstName: Control;
        //Constructor
        constructor(private builder: FormBuilder,
            private testingService: TestingService) {
            this._formGroup();
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.resmessage = "";
        }
        //Form Group
        _formGroup() {
            //Set Initial Values to the Control & Validators
            this.firstName = new Control('', Validators.required);
            this.testingForm = this.builder.group({
                firstName: this.firstName
            });
        }
        saveContact(Testing) {
            this.testingService.saveTesting(Testing)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.resmessage = response;
                });
        }
    }
```

**Testing.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Component}                            from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Request, RequestMethod, Response,
    RequestOptions, Headers}                              from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable}                                       from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Testingmodel}                                     from './Testing.model';

@Component({
    providers: [Http]
})

@Injectable()
export class TestingService {
    public headers: Headers;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    public _saveUrl: string = 'api/Testing/PostTesting';

    saveTesting(testing: Testingmodel): Observable<string> {
        //debugger
        let body = JSON.stringify(testing);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        //http.post(url: string, body: string, options ?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
        return this._http.post(this._saveUrl, body, options)
            .map(res => res.json().message)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Opps!! Server error');
    }
}
```

**Testing.view.html**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <form [ngFormModel]="testingForm">
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error' : !firstName.valid }">
                <label class="control-label" for="firstName">Username</label>
                <em *ngIf="!firstName.valid">*</em>
                <input id="firstName" type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="FirstName" [ngFormControl]="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveTesting(testingForm.value)">
                    Create
                </button>

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Package.jason**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: @AJT_82 any idea ??

Comment: Oh... you seem to be using a beta version... Hmmh. Hard for me to debug then.

Comment: Ok do you have any way i have tried every possible thing that came to my mind ..tats why i am here  to get where i am wrong...if you have any approx idea please share @AJT_82

Comment: Yes I'm looking into it right now :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to grasp your `testing.component.ts`-file. It's been ages since I user beta version, so trying hard to remember.

But: If `testing.main.ts` is "connected" to `testing.view`-html, it will of course produce error, since you have in both `testing.main` and `testing.component` referred to the same html-view:

```
templateUrl: `app/Testing/Testing.view.html`
```

You have correctly "connected" the view to your correct ts-file, meaning your `testing.main.ts`-file. But you now have two components referring to the same html view. Remove the line

```
templateUrl: `app/Testing/Testing.view.html`
```

from your testing.component.

To be honest I don't understand what the testing.component is for, but at least it is working fine when I removed that file from the app. Here is a working plunker to demonstrate that! [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3qCKADmpAXAjf7bHUEnW?p=preview)

EDIT2: Well, I went ahead and modified the plunker instead, so here is the correct testing.component. As earlier said, you need to remove the templateUrl: `app/Testing/Testing.view.html` from your testing.component, as it will not work. Instead, if you want to use `<router-outlet>`, that needs to be placed there instead:

So like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testing',
  template: `
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TestingMain]

})

@RouteConfig([
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'TestingMain',
      component: TestingMain,
      useAsDefault: true
    }
])

export class AppComponent {

}
```

### Here is again an updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WUEYmvFSekmqWyzjwibD?p=preview)

Comment: yes issues are coming due to beta version so i will use stable version...still getting errors

Comment: Well what kind of errors are you getting now? Hard to tell anything more, I just took the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82  its the cache that why not reflecting changes..its working now.. i have added my change..does it makes sense now

Comment: i want to add here instead of View name in 'Testing.component' use  below code: template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Could you take the plunker I provided and add your routes etc, so that I would have something to debug :)

Comment: @stylishCoder Well, I went ahead and did it myself again. So now there is an updated answer and fully working plunker.

Comment: @stylishCoder, did this answer help you? If so, would you kindly accept this answer? :)

Comment: yes i have accepted the answer.. i wan to thank you for guiding me.. i am beginner to angular 2

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help. By accepting my answer I meant that you would mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :) But anyway, glad I could help. Angular is hard to grasp in the beginning, but when you get into it, it starts to make sense after a while :)